# Installing Tensorflow in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, path, tensorflow

Details. I'm installing on Windows 10, I'm using pythong 3.5.4, I've installed the visual studio 15 dependencies and .dll's (unless I need to change some PATH variables). I have already updated CUDA in path and installed that and the same for cuDNN. However, I'm getting this error both when installing via conda environment and a pip install.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Looks like some .dll isn't being called correctly, but I'm really unsure as which as I've already installed them all and checked. Perhaps the Visual studio 15 dependencies?

Also this is Tensorflow for GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is commonly associated with a wrong cuDNN version being used.

Assuming you're using the lastest Tensorflow version released (i.e. 1.3.0), **you need to use cuDNN 6 despite the Tensorflow install page telling you to use 5.1**. Since the latestrelease they build against Tensorflow 6 for all their binary releases ([or so their changelong claims](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-130)), so you should use that.

Note that you can have both cuDNN 5.1 and 6 installed (just put them in two different folders and put b0th folders on your `PATH` environment variable), since the .dll files have different names and only the right one will be loaded.

Comment: When installing cuDNN I did it the way nVidia said in their documentation and put the 3 files in the appropriate CUDA files which were already in the PATH. I'll try redoing the cuDNN part and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I figured out the problem. For some reason I got too ambitious and installed cuDNN 7.0 which was just released with Tensorflow. When I reinstalled with the proper 6.0 it worked. I did get a few warnings however :

Comment: 2017-08-25 08:02:12.511272: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-25 08:02:12.511367: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

Comment: Those warnings are perfectly normal, they appear because the tensorflow version you're using is the default one from Google that is not optimized for your CPU (there's another stackoverflow question about that that can give you more details)

Comment: Great thanks for the help. I just have to figure out where to find that file to edit so that it runs off of my GPU instead.

Comment: There is no such thing! If you installed the GPU version, it already does run on your GPU (assuming cuDNN and CUDA are installed correctly obviously). The message you see is always printed. Some operations will of course run on the CPU (not everything can be pushed to the GPU..) but as long as you have a GPU available tensorflow will use it by default

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know that. I guess there have been changes, because most of the older walkthroughs and guides don't say that. Thanks!